# Save multiple table rows with one save button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables, save

I am using the following code to save a row in a datatable using a save button

```
  $(document).on('click','.updateOrder', function(){
            var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            var rejectReasons = { PersistRejectReasons :[] }
            var jsonReturnObj = new Object();

            jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber = thisRow.find('.dt_orderNo').text();
            jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber = thisRow.find('.dt_orderLineNo').text();
            jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode = thisRow.find('.dt_researchOutcome').find("option:selected").prop("value");
            jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes = thisRow.find('.dt_researchNotes').find('input').val();

            if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != "" && jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != null) {
                if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode =="14. Other") {
                    if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes == "" || jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes == "null") {
                        alert(" Please add Research Notes");
                        jsonReturnObj.Processed = false;
                        $('#orderReportTable').append("call failed");
                        throw new Exception("Error message");
    }
                }
                jsonReturnObj.Processed = true;
            }else {
                jsonReturnObj.Processed = false;
            }

            if($("#movedInput"+jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber+"-"+jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber).is(':checked')){
                jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = false;
            }else{
                jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = true;
            }

            rejectReasons.PersistRejectReasons.push(jsonReturnObj);
            var jsonReturnString = JSON.stringify(rejectReasons);
            console.log("Rejecting Store Number is "+$("#storeNum").val())

            var request2 = $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'RejectingStoreNum': $("#storeNum").val(), //thisRow.find('.dt_storeNo').text(), //thisRow.find("td").eq(16).text(),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                type: "POST",

                url: "persistStoreResearchOutcome", // REST endpoint. replace url1 with REST Endpoint
                data : jsonReturnString,//json data. use data and contentType attributes for POST requests.
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "text",
                /*xhrFields: {
                    'withCredentials': true //Tell browser to provide credentials
                },*/
                crossDomain: true,// this is for cross domain requests*/
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR){
                    console.log("status:"+status);
                    $('#orderReportTable').append("call successful");
                    if(jsonReturnObj.Processed){
                        thisRow.find('.dt_itemStatus').text("Researched");
                        table.draw();
                    }else{
                        thisRow.find('.dt_itemStatus').text("Active");
                        table.draw();
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
                    //console.log("failed: status:"+status);
                    $('#orderReportTable').append("call failed, error"+errorThrown);
                    alert("There was an error while trying to save this item");
                }
            });
        });
```

I want to do the same processing but for all the rows in the table with one single click.I used the each function to loop over the rows but keep getting an error

```
$("table tr").each(function (){
                console.log(this);
                var thisRow = $(this).closest('td');
                var rejectReasons = { PersistRejectReasons :[] }
                var jsonReturnObj = new Object();

                jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber = thisRow.find('.dt_orderNo').text();
                jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber = thisRow.find('.dt_orderLineNo').text();
                jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode = thisRow.find('.dt_researchOutcome').find("option:selected").prop("value");
                jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes = $(this).find('.dt_researchNotes').find('input').val();

                if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != "" && jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != null) {
                    if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode =="14. Other") {
                        if(jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes == "" || jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonNotes == "null") {
                            alert(" Please add Research Notes");
                            jsonReturnObj.Processed = false;
                            $('#orderReportTable').append("call failed");
                            throw new Exception("Error message");
                        }
                    }
                    jsonReturnObj.Processed = true;
                }else {
                    jsonReturnObj.Processed = false;
                }

                if($("#movedInput"+jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber+"-"+jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber).is(':checked')){
                    jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = false;
                }else{
                    jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = true;
                }

                rejectReasons.PersistRejectReasons.push(jsonReturnObj);
                var jsonReturnString = JSON.stringify(rejectReasons);
                console.log("Rejecting Store Number is "+$("#storeNum").val())

                var request2 = $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'RejectingStoreNum': $("#storeNum").val(), //thisRow.find('.dt_storeNo').text(), //thisRow.find("td").eq(16).text(),
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    type: "POST",

                    url: "persistStoreResearchOutcome", // REST endpoint. replace url1 with REST Endpoint
                    data : jsonReturnString,//json data. use data and contentType attributes for POST requests.
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "text",
                    /*xhrFields: {
                        'withCredentials': true //Tell browser to provide credentials
                    },*/
                    crossDomain: true,// this is for cross domain requests*/
                    success: function (data, status, jqXHR){
                        console.log("status:"+status);
                       // $('#orderReportTable').append("call successful");
                        if(jsonReturnObj.Processed){
                            this.find('.dt_itemStatus').text("Researched");
                            table.draw();
                        }else{
                            this.find('.dt_itemStatus').text("Active");
                            table.draw();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown){
                        //console.log("failed: status:"+status);
                        $('#orderReportTable').append("call failed, error"+errorThrown);
                        alert("There was an error while trying to save this item");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

How can I fix this?
The error message is

```
http://localhost:8080/persistStoreResearchOutcome 500 ()
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):544
each @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):509
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

I tried different ways to loop over the table including the every() function from datatables,but keep getting the same error

Comment: The problem is on server side as request to `http://localhost:8080/persistStoreResearchOutcome` returns HTTP 500 - Server Error.

Comment: yes,but i still am not sure if I am loooping correctly.If this actually will loop through all the rows and repeat the same series of steps

Comment: It's erroring out at line 509 which is - $("table tr").each(function (){
So I don't think it has anything to do with the server side.Any pointers will be appreciated